# How can I read data sent to my server ip address and a specific port using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I am building a software where I've to show the real-time data which is coming from a different server to my IP address and a specific port, How can I read that data using PHP language?

Comment: "How can I read data sent to my server ip address and a specific port using PHP?" Do you have access to terminal/(linux) screen/deamon to keep a possible PHP server running which can listen on a port?

Comment: No sir, I am new to socket programming and I've no idea about that. Can you please tell me how can I do that?